# Invert SVG curve

Tags: svg

I know how to create a svg path that is curved 'downwards'. But I am attempting to invert the curve (ie make it curve upwards).

I'm unsure if there is an attribute to invert the curve...`invert="true"`? Or will I need to recalculate the coordinates.

Below is my example of my 'downard' curve. I wish to invert this upwards.

```html
<svg width="500" height="80" viewBox="0 0 500 80" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width: 100%;">
    <path class="header-base" d="M0,0 L0,40 Q250,80 500,40 L500,0 Z" fill="black"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Are you looking for an svg-only solution or are you open to css?

Comment: @Danield I'm open to both, prefer svg though

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter in the Q command set a control point for the curve.

Since the curve begins at 0,40 and ends at 500,40 the y base is 40 . Any value lower than that (for instance, 20) will set the control point upwards and make the curve bend this way. A lower value will make the curve go upwards.

```html
<svg width="500" height="80" viewBox="0 0 500 80" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width: 100%;">
    <path class="header-base" d="M0,0 L0,40 Q250,20 500,40 L500,0 Z" fill="black"></path>
</svg>
```